# How to chain Django querysets preserving individual order

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I'd like to append or chain several Querysets in Django, preserving the order of each one (not the result). I'm using a third-party library to paginate the result, and it only accepts lists or querysets. I've tried these options:

**Queryset join**: Doesn't preserve ordering in individual querysets, so I can't use this.

```
result = queryset_1 | queryset_2
```

**Using itertools**: Calling `list()` on the chain object actually evaluates the querysets and this could cause a lot of overhead. Doesn't it?

```
result = list(itertools.chain(queryset_1, queryset_2))
```

How do you think I should go?

Answer (score 15):

This solution prevents duplicates:

```
q1 = Q(...)
q2 = Q(...)
q3 = Q(...)
qs = (
    Model.objects
    .filter(q1 | q2 | q3)
    .annotate(
        search_type_ordering=Case(
            When(q1, then=Value(2)),
            When(q2, then=Value(1)),
            When(q3, then=Value(0)),
            default=Value(-1),
            output_field=IntegerField(),
        )
    )
    .order_by('-search_type_ordering', ...)
)
```

Comment: This has the added benefit of allowing the resulting queryset to be filtered. IMO, it's the optimal answer so far!

Comment: I like the idea of this answer.

Comment: This can result in duplicates if the the `Q` object filters result in a `LEFT JOIN` where some `Model` objects are compared in the `CASE` more than one times. See this for a better solution: https://stackoverflow.com/q/38583295/9835872

Answer (score 9):

If the querysets are of different models, you have to evaluate them to lists and then you can just append:

```
result = list(queryset_1) + list(queryset_2)
```

If they are the same model, you should combine the queries using the [Q object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) and 'order_by("queryset_1 field", "queryset_2 field")'.

The right answer largely depends on why you want to combine these and how you are going to use the results.

Comment: I'm doing a complex seach on the same model splitted in several queries. Each one retrieves records that match a certain condition and each one is ordered in a particular way. The result must include the results from each queryset and must maintain the order of each of these querysets. Therefore, I can't use `Q` objects here, as I wouldn't be allowed to do several `order_by()` on the same query. I would like to avoid calling `list()` on each queryset to avoid accessing the database, obtaining too many objects in memory.

Comment: Do you think it's possible to compose a pure SQL query that would return a single set of rows ordered and filtered exactly as you want? If not, then a single QuerySet can't do it either. If you order two result sets in incompatible ways, for example. If you work around this incompatibility using a complex join from two distinctly ordered result sets, that's not something django ORM can do.

Comment: I don't want to get into pure SQL as much as I can stay with Django's ORM. I was just asking this to see if there is a better alternative for what I'm doing (currently using second example) with a limited query to avoid having thousands of objects in memory.

Comment: I'm not suggesting you do pure SQL. The answer to the question "Is a single SQL query here possible without complex joins?" is the same as to "Is a single QuerySet possible?". If you can compose such a query, you can reason about how to compose a similar QS.

Comment: Yes, I could do the query in SQL, but I'd use SQL unions (although I don't know if they preserve order)

Comment: SQL unions do not preserve order. However, that can be worked around like so: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21181664/sql-server-union-but-keep-order

@Caumons I'm facing a similar problem as you were. The link I pasted above can be worked in SQL, but I need a way of doing that in Django's ORM. Would you be able to help here?

Answer (score 5):

So, inspired by [Peter's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54762468/2533340) this is what I did in my project (Django 2.2):

```py
from django.db import models
from .models import MyModel

# Add an extra field to each query with a constant value
queryset_0 = MyModel.objects.annotate(
    qs_order=models.Value(0, models.IntegerField())
)

# Each constant should basically act as the position where we want the 
# queryset to stay
queryset_1 = MyModel.objects.annotate(
    qs_order=models.Value(1, models.IntegerField()) 
)

[...]

queryset_n = MyModel.objects.annotate(
    qs_order=models.Value(n, models.IntegerField()) 
)

# Finally, I ordered the union result by that extra field.
union = queryset_0.union(
    queryset_1, 
    queryset_2, 
    [...], 
    queryset_n).order_by('qs_order')
```

With this, I could order the resulting union as I wanted without changing any private attribute while only evaluating the querysets once.

Comment: this approach putting me into trouble. Can't filter or get values_list from the query once union is applied.

Comment: Yeah... that's the problem with union. As stated in the docs (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#union) , you can't filter on the resulting queryset. You have to filter before the union...

Comment: The behaviour of union is to remove duplicates. But after applying this annotation and order_by duplicates are cropping up.

Comment: @SandeepBalagopal, for that you would have to use UNION ALL, but I don't think Django ORM has this... If I ever had the use case, I think I would have to fallback using a raw sql statement.

Comment: @SandeepBalagopal and others having issues with not being able to filter after using `.union()`. An alternative is to use Django's `|` operate. This merges two querysets but allows you filter on the resulting queryset.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure this solution works in every possible case, but it looks like the result is the union of two QuerySets (on the same model) preserving the order of the first one:

```
union = qset1.union(qset2)
union.query.extra_order_by = qset1.query.extra_order_by
union.query.order_by = qset1.query.order_by
union.query.default_ordering = qset1.query.default_ordering
union.query.get_meta().ordering = qset1.query.get_meta().ordering
```

I did not test it extensively, so before you use that code in production, make sure it behaves like expected.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to **merge two querysets into a third queryset**, here is an example, using `_result_cache`.

**model**

```
class ImportMinAttend(models.Model):
    country=models.CharField(max_length=2, blank=False, null=False)
    status=models.CharField(max_length=5, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
```

From this model, I want to display a list of all the rows such that :

1. (query 1) empty status go first, ordered by countries
2. (query 2) non empty status go in second, ordered by countries

I want to merge query 1 and query 2.

```
    #get all the objects
    queryset=ImportMinAttend.objects.all()

    #get the first queryset
    queryset_1=queryset.filter(status=None).order_by("country")
    #len or anything that hits the database
    len(queryset_1)

    #get the second queryset
    queryset_2=queryset.exclude(status=None).order_by("country")

    #append the second queryset to the first one AND PRESERVE ORDER
    for query in queryset_2:
         queryset_1._result_cache.append(query)

    #final result
    queryset=queryset_1
```

It might not be very efficient, but it works :).

Comment: This seems to be much more efficient than calling list() on both querysets. If you iterate over the smallest this seems better. What I don't like is modifying the private attribute _result_cache... Are you sure this is safe?

Comment: This approach will still evaluate all querysets which is the same as creating a list of them which is what the author of the question does not want.

Answer (score 0):

For Django 1.11 (released on April 4, 2017) use union() for this,  documentation here:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.union

Here is the Version 2.1 link to this:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#union

Comment: Downvoting because this does not preserve the order of the querysets.

Answer (score 0):

the union() function to combine multiple querysets together, rather than the `or` (`|`) operator. This avoids a very inefficient OUTER JOIN query that reads the entire table.

Answer (score -1):

If two querysets has common field, you can order combined queryset by that field. Querysets are not evaluated during this operation.

For example:

```
class EventsHistory(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    event_time = models.DateTimeField()
    event_id = models.IntegerField()

class EventsOperational(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    event_time = models.DateTimeField()
    event_id = models.IntegerField()

qs1 = EventsHistory.objects.all()
qs2 = EventsOperational.objects.all()

qs_combined = qs2.union(qs1).order_by('event_time')
```

Comment: This is not what the author wanted though. He doesn't want to order by a single field. As each subquery was selected a certain way, he wants to mantain the ordering each subquery uses. I'm facing the same issue right now.

Comment: This returns inconsistent results.