# Sql server union but keep order

Tags: sql-server

Is there a way to union two tables, but keep the rows from the first table appearing first in the result set?

For example:

Table1

```
name        surname
-------------------
John         Doe
Bob          Marley
Ras          Tafari
```

Table2

```
name       surname
------------------
Lucky      Dube
Abby       Arnold
```

I want the result set to look like:

```
name        surname
-------------------
John        Doe
Bob         Marley 
Ras         Tafari
Lucky       Dube
Abby        Arnold
```

Unfortunately, `union` somehow reorders the table. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Try this :-

```
Select * 
from
( 
Select name,surname, 1 as filter
from  Table1
Union all
Select name,surname , 2 as filter
from Table2
)
order by filter
```

Comment: @information_interchange It works less because it's designed to work that way, but more as a side-effect of the internal handling of the UNION ALL vs the UNION operation. UNION will always eliminate rows that are duplicated between queries. In order to do this efficiently, the server must sort the rows first. UNION ALL allows duplicates, and so no inter-query sorting is required. The server improves performance by not doing the unnecessary sorting, unless you specify an ORDER BY clause.

Answer (score 17):

The only way to guarantee output order is to use `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT name,surname,1 as rs
FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT name,surname,2
FROM table2
ORDER BY rs
```

If you don't want `rs` to appear in the final result set, do the `UNION` as a subquery:

```
SELECT name,surname
FROM (
  SELECT name,surname,1 as rs
  FROM table1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT name,surname,2
  FROM table2
) t
ORDER BY rs
```

Comment: You could additionally order by `surname` if that's necessary, but after `rs`. Thorough answer though.

Comment: +1.. union all doesn't guarantee.. you need a subquery like you did :)

Answer (score 8):

```
;WITH cte as (
    SELECT name, surname, 1 as n FROM table1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT name, surname, 2 as n FROM table2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT name, surname, 3 as n FROM table3
)
SELECT name, surname
FROM cte
ORDER BY n;
```

Answer (score 1):

.Like this?

```
CREATE TABLE #Table1 (Names VARCHAR(50))
CREATE TABLE #Table2 (Names VARCHAR(50))

INSERT INTO #Table1
(
    Names
)
VALUES
    ('John Doe'), ('Bob Marley'), ('Ras Tafari') 

INSERT INTO #Table2
(
    Names
)
VALUES
    ('Lucky Dube'), ('Abby Arnold') 


SELECT ArbSeq   = 1, *
FROM #Table1
UNION ALL
SELECT ArbSeq   = 2, *
FROM #Table2
ORDER BY ArbSeq
```

It should be noted that ordering is not guaranteed when not explicitly defined.
If the table features a clustered index, the rows will typically be returned in the index's order - but this is not guaranteed.

Comment: clustered index does *nothing* to guarantee ordering.

Comment: thanks, see edit. its your italics that really made me pay attention.