# Combining two columns data into one using SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table:

```
create table test
(
   cola varchar(10),
   colb varchar(10)
)
```

With some records:

```
cola    colb
------------
 A       B
 C       D
 E       F
 G       H
```

I want to show the result in the following format:

```
columnName
----------
 A
 C
 E
 G
 B
 D
 F
 H
```

## Attempt:

```
select cola+colb as columnName from test;
```

Gives me:

```
columnName
------------
AB
CD
EF
GH
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sql server union but keep order](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21181664/sql-server-union-but-keep-order)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [`UNION`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp) operation for this task. Here's your required query.

```
select cola as columnName
from test
union
select colb as columnName 
from test
```

**NOTE:** `UNION` will keep only one record in case of duplicate values between `cola` and `colb`. If you want to see the duplicate values repeated in your result, use the `UNION ALL` operation instead.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to store above result into variable?

Comment: If you want to store one value at a time into a variable, use a cursor. If you want to store the entire result into a single variable, one way would be to store it as comma separated values. There are tons of questions on SO giving the various methods to implement the second solution. Just hit the search button.