# How to prevent sorting in proc sql union in SAS?

Tags: sql, sas, union

I'm doing a union of multiple select statements based on different tables. The problem is the output is automatically sorted by TOTAL_NUM column instead of staying in the order I did the union in. Is there a way to avoid this?

Here's a sample of my code.

```
proc sql;
SELECT COUNT(loannumber) AS TOTAL_NUM, SUM(LoanAmt) as LOAN_AMOUNT FROM sub_620 WHERE Flag = 1
union
SELECT COUNT(loannumber) AS TOTAL_NUM, SUM(LoanAmt) as LOAN_AMOUNT FROM 620_639 WHERE Flag = 1
union
SELECT COUNT(loannumber) AS TOTAL_NUM, SUM(LoanAmt) as LOAN_AMOUNT FROM 640_660 WHERE Flag = 1
union
SELECT COUNT(loannumber) AS TOTAL_NUM, SUM(LoanAmt) as LOAN_AMOUNT FROM V700_719 WHERE Flag = 1
union
SELECT COUNT(loannumber) AS TOTAL_NUM, SUM(LoanAmt) as LOAN_AMOUNT FROM 720_739 WHERE Flag = 1
union
SELECT COUNT(loannumber) AS TOTAL_NUM, SUM(LoanAmt) as LOAN_AMOUNT FROM 740_759 WHERE Flag = 1;
run;
```

The output is like this, but sorted on TOTAL_NUM instead of the order of statements. 
[image]

Comment: Sorry just found this answer explaining it.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21181664/sql-server-union-but-keep-order

Comment: There's no guarantee that it will keep the order within table. SQL row order isn't guaranteed unless you explicitly order it exactly as you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want SQL to order the output then give it something it can sort on.

```
proc sql;
  SELECT 1 as ORDER,COUNT(loannumber) AS TOTAL_NUM, SUM(LoanAmt) as LOAN_AMOUNT
    FROM sub_620 WHERE Flag = 1
  union
  SELECT 2 as ORDER,COUNT(loannumber) AS TOTAL_NUM, SUM(LoanAmt) as LOAN_AMOUNT
    FROM 620_639 WHERE Flag = 1
  order by 1
  ;
quit;
```

Answer (score 3):

> Unless an ORDER BY clause is included in the SELECT statement, then a particular order to the output rows, such as the order in which the rows are encountered in the queried table, cannot be guaranteed, even if an index is present. Without an ORDER BY clause, the order of the output rows is determined by the internal processing of PROC SQL, the default collating sequence of SAS, and your operating environment. Therefore, if you want your result table to appear in a particular order, then use the ORDER BY clause.

http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/sqlproc/69049/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p1jr2es0aus2qtn11peo724tt8f4.htm

Your tables will be ordered in your output but there's no guarantee the rows within the table are the same.

Answer (score 1):

Use `UNION ALL`:

```
proc sql;
    SELECT COUNT(loannumber) AS TOTAL_NUM, SUM(LoanAmt) as LOAN_AMOUNT FROM sub_620 WHERE Flag = 1
    union all
    SELECT COUNT(loannumber) AS TOTAL_NUM, SUM(LoanAmt) as LOAN_AMOUNT FROM 620_639 WHERE Flag = 1
    union all
    SELECT COUNT(loannumber) AS TOTAL_NUM, SUM(LoanAmt) as LOAN_AMOUNT FROM 640_660 WHERE Flag = 1
    union
    SELECT COUNT(loannumber) AS TOTAL_NUM, SUM(LoanAmt) as LOAN_AMOUNT FROM V700_719 WHERE Flag = 1
    union all
    SELECT COUNT(loannumber) AS TOTAL_NUM, SUM(LoanAmt) as LOAN_AMOUNT FROM 720_739 WHERE Flag = 1
    union
    SELECT COUNT(loannumber) AS TOTAL_NUM, SUM(LoanAmt) as LOAN_AMOUNT FROM 740_759 WHERE Flag = 1;
    run;
```

`UNION` incurs the additional overhead of removing duplicates (hence the sort).  `UNION ALL` does not remove duplicates.

Comment: I tried that initially and ran a few validation checks and it worked out. When I checked out a large subset though I realized it was out of order. So union all didn't work for me.

Comment: "out of order"?  SQL result sets are *unordered*.  If you want them in a particular order, then you need to use an `ORDER BY`.  However, I would instead recommend that you include a third column that specifies where the data is coming from.

Comment: That's what I figured out. Here's a link showing it in more detail for anyone else wondering http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21181664/sql-server-union-but-keep-order.