# Prevent sort result of union in entity framework after select and distinct

Tags: entity-framework, sorting, distinct, union

Before I asked [Prevent sort result of union in entity framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41101343/prevent-sort-result-of-union-in-entity-framework)

I got my answer but now I have new problem with this issue. I have this code:

```
var productExactlyTitle = products.Where(x => x.Title == keyword);
var productStartWithPhrase = products.Where(x => x.Title.StartsWith(keyword));
var productStartWithWord = products.Where(x => x.Title.StartsWith(keyword + " "));
var productContainsWord = products.Where(x => x.Title.Contains(" " + keyword + " "));
var productContainsPhrase = products.Where(x => x.Title.Contains(keyword)
                                               || x.Title.Contains(keyword)
                                               || x.SubTitle.Contains(keyword)
                                               || x.OtherName.Contains(keyword));


var splitWords = keyword.Split(' ');
var productSplitWordSearch = splitWords.Aggregate(products, (current, word) => current.Where(x => x.Title.Contains(word.Trim())));


var p1 = productExactlyTitle.Select(x => new { Item = x, Order = 1 });
var p2 = productStartWithWord.Select(x => new { Item = x, Order = 2 });
var p3 = productStartWithPhrase.Select(x => new { Item = x, Order = 3 });
var p4 = productContainsWord.Select(x => new { Item = x, Order = 4 });
var p5 = productContainsPhrase.Select(x => new { Item = x, Order = 5 });
var p6 = productSplitWordSearch.Select(x => new { Item = x, Order = 6 });

var productList = p1
    .Union(p2)
    .Union(p3)
    .Union(p4)
    .Union(p5)
    .Union(p6)
    .OrderBy(x => x.Order)
    .Take(21)
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Select(x => new ProductItemViewModel()
    {
        Id = x.Item.Id,
        Title = x.Item.Title,
        Price = DiscountController.ApplyDiscountToPrice(x.Item).ToPrice(),
        Image = x.Item.Images.FirstOrDefault(y => y.IsCoverPhoto)?.ImageUrl
    });
```

Result of above code have duplicate records and I have to use `select` and `distinct` to remove duplicate records. so I change my code like this:

```
var productList = p1
    .Union(p2)
    .Union(p3)
    .Union(p4)
    .Union(p5)
    .Union(p6)
    .OrderBy(x => x.Order)
    .Select(x => x.Item)
    .Distinct()
    .Take(21)
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Select(x => new ProductItemViewModel()
    {
        Id = x.Id,
        Title = x.Title,
        Price = DiscountController.ApplyDiscountToPrice(x).ToPrice(),
        Image = x.Images.FirstOrDefault(y => y.IsCoverPhoto)?.ImageUrl
    });
```

But after that my result is sorted with `Id` column **again**.

How can I solved this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, since adding `Order` field to each query makes the record unique, using `Union` (which is supposed to remove duplicates) doesn't make sense, so simply use `Concat` instead.

Second, to remove duplicates and not lose the `Order` field needed for later ordering, you need to group by `Item` and take the minimum `Order` for each group. The rest is the same as in the original solution.

```
var productList = p1
    .Concat(p2)
    .Concat(p3)
    .Concat(p4)
    .Concat(p5)
    .Concat(p6)
    .GroupBy(e => e.Item)
    .Select(g => new { Item = g.Key, Order = g.Min(e => e.Order) })
    .OrderBy(e => e.Order)
    .Select(e => e.Item)
    .Take(21)
    .AsEnumerable()
    ...
```