# MySQl how to make two merge two tables result with union all or any alternative

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table containing nations, regions and sub region.

A nation has several region, a ragion has several subregion.

I have to order them first by nation, then region and than subregion

So far so good I can handle this easily and I am writing the following query

```
SELECT * FROM NATION ORDER BY NAME ASC , REGION ASC, SUBREGION ASC
```

Until here no issues...

Unfortunatly I have been asked to put Italy as first in the list preserving all the sorting I have mentioned above.

The result should look like this:

Nation  Region  Subregion

ITALY   A   A

ITALY   A   B

ITALY   A   C

ITALY   B   A

ITALY   B   B

ALBANIA A   A

ALBANIA A   B

ALBANIA A   C

ALBANIA B   A

ALBANIA B   B

...

My not working solution is to have two queries, one selecting only italy with all the region and subregions and than another one to selecting where italy is not present and at the and use "UNION ALL" on those two table.
Unfortunatly UNION ALL does not preserve the sorting.

The two queries alone are working perfectly but when I am using union they are not preserving the order I was expecting:

```
    SELECT * FROM NATION WHERE NAME = 'ITALY' ORDER BY NAME ASC , REGION ASC, SUBREGION ASC 
UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM NATION WHERE NOT NAME = 'ITALY' ORDER BY NAME ASC , REGION ASC, SUBREGION ASC
```

I have tried Union All and I have red several articles from the web such as:

[Sql server union but keep order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21181664/sql-server-union-but-keep-order)

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/preserve-select-order-within-mysql-union

and many other but I have closed my browser tabs so I can not link them.

I have tried to even do something like

```
SELECT *, 1 as filter FROM NATION WHERE NAME = 'ITALY' ORDER BY NAME ASC , REGION ASC, SUBREGION ASC
UNION ALL
SELECT *, 2 as filter FROM NATION WHERE NAME != 'ITALY' ORDER BY NAME ASC , REGION ASC, SUBREGION ASC
ORDER BY RS
```

Didn't work

and tried also this without success

```
WITH cte as(
SELECT *, 1 as filter FROM NATION WHERE NAME = 'ITALY' ORDER BY NAME ASC , REGION ASC, SUBREGION ASC
    UNION ALL
    SELECT *, 2 as filter FROM NATION WHERE NAME != 'ITALY' ORDER BY NAME ASC , REGION ASC, SUBREGION ASC
    ORDER BY RS)
select* from CTE
ORDER BY RS
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply add a condition to the `order by`:

```
select n.*
from nation n
where (name = 'ITALY') desc,  -- put Italy first
      name, region subregion
```