# Django: NotImplementedError: annotate() + distinct(fields) is not implemented

Tags: python, django, postgresql

There are 2 simple models:

```
class Question(TimeStampedModel):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=40)

class Answer(TimeStampedModel):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, related_name='answers')
    is_agreed = models.BooleanField()
    author = models.ForeingKey(User, related_name='answers')
```

And there is my problem:

```
In [18]: Question.objects.count()
Out[18]: 3
```

I need to annotate queryset with 'is_user_agreed' and 'answers_amount' fields:

```
In [18]: user = User.objects.first() 
In [19]: qs = Question.objects.annotate(
    ...:             is_user_agreed=Case(
    ...:                 When(answers__in=user.answers.filter(is_agreed=True), then=Value(True)),
    ...:                 When(answers__in=user.answers.filter(is_agreed=False), then=Value(False)),
    ...:                 default=Value(None),
    ...:                 output_field=NullBooleanField(),
    ...:             ),
    ...:         ).annotate(answers_amount=Count('answers'))
    ...: qs.count()
Out[19]: 4
```

**^ here count is 4, but I have only 3 questions in db** :(
So, I've tried with `distinct()`

```
In [20]: qs.distinct().count()
Out[20]: 4  # but distinct doesn't work

In [21]: qs.distinct('id').count()
```

And after last line of code I've got this exception:

```
NotImplementedError: annotate() + distinct(fields) is not implemented.
```

I've also tried to use this trick `annotate(Count('id')).filter(id__count__gt=1)`

But in this case I'm losing all duplicate rows, and qs.count() is 2.

**UPDATE:** The problem is duplicated rows in queryset.

**SOLUTION:** (Extended variant of Vladimir's second approach)

```
user = User.objects.first()
user_agreed_questions = user.answers.filter(
    is_agreed=True).values_list('question_id', flat=True)

user_not_agreed_questions = user.answers.filter(
    is_agreed=False).values_list('question_id', flat=True)

Question.objects.annotate(
    answer_amount=Count('answers'),
    is_user_agreed=Case(
         When(id__in=user_agreed_questions, then=True),
         When(id__in=user_not_agreed_questions, then=False),
         default=None,
         output_field=NullBooleanField(),
    ),
)
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do, but [this question may help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13145254/django-annotate-count-with-a-distinct-field).

Comment: Are you using postgres?

Comment: In short, you join Question and Answer tables. So if 1st question has two answers, 2nd question has one answer, 3rd question has one onswer, you will get 4 (2 + 1 + 1). Can you describe what desired result of queryset is? What do you want to get?

Comment: @Sayse yes, postgres

Comment: @VladimirDanilov I want to get queryset with all anotated questions (3 qyestions). And it must be without duplicates.

Comment: Can't clearly understand from your queryset what you really try to archive. All users agreed with all answers? Something else?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this:

```
Question.objects.annotate(
    answer_amount=Count('answers'),
    is_user_agreed=F('answers__is_agreed'),
).order_by('id', '-answers__is_agreed').distinct('id')
```

If `question` has no `answers`, then `question.is_user_agreed` is `None`. If `question` has at least one `answer` with `answer.is_agreed=True`, then `question.is_agreed` is `True`. Otherwise, `is_user_agreed` is `False`.

Or this:

```
agreed_questons = Answer.objects.filter(
    is_agreed=True,
).values_list('question_id', flat=True).distinct()

Question.objects.annotate(
    answer_amount=Count('answers'),
    is_agreed=Case(
        When(id__in=agreed_questions, then=True),
        When(answers__isnull=True, then=None),
        default=False,
        output_field=NullBooleanField(),
    ),
)
```

`agreed_questons` is list of `id` of `questions`, that have at least one `answer` with `answer.is_agreed=True`.

Comment: My annotates works well, the main problem is duplicate entries in result quesryset.

Comment: I've checked your second approach and it works for me (details in question). Many thanks!