# Django's NotImplementedError: aggregate() + distinct(fields) not implemented

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have quite simple models:

```py
class Profile(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    age = models.IntegerField(default=18)


class Place(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)


class ProfilePlaceFeedback(models.Model):
    profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='feedback_set')
    place = models.ForeignKey(Place, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='feedback_set')
    review = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    rating = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

`ProfilePlaceFeedback` - is model to store each rating left by user.
And to count the rating for some `place`, I need to retrieve all **LATEST** User feedbacks and sum up all rating values. Here's the code for retrieving all last feedbacks by each user:

```
place.feedback_set.order_by('profile', '-timestamp').distinct('profile')
```

But making querying:

```
place.feedback_set.order_by('profile', '-timestamp').distinct('profile').aggregate(Sum(rating))
```

Raises exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/PATH_TO_VIRTUALENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 357, in aggregate
    raise NotImplementedError("aggregate() + distinct(fields) not implemented.")
NotImplementedError: aggregate() + distinct(fields) not implemented.
```

Using Django 2.0 and postgresql as database.

Please help me with this problem :)

Comment: this may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38583295/djangos-notimplementederror-annotate-distinctfields-is-not-implemented/38586709#38586709

Comment: It seems that you need to group by profile.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for aggregate data like this:

```
from django.db.models import F

Profile
.objects
.values(profile_name=F('name'),            
        place_name=F('profileplacefeedback__place__name'),
        )
.annotate(timestamp=Max('profileplacefeedback__timestamp'),
          rating=Sum('profileplacefeedback__rating'))
.order_by( 'profile_name', '-timestamp')
```

If you need more data, just add it on `values` section.

*Disclaimer: query not tested here, just wrote by hand. Let me know if it fails to fix it or delete the answer (in order to help future users)*

**Edited** After OP Comment:

> I need to calculate an average rating for a given place and filtering only last rating left by profile.

You are looking for [FirstValue](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/database-functions/#firstvalue) of [django window functions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/expressions/#window-functions).

```
from django.db.models import Avg,  F, RowRange, Window
from django.db.models.functions.window import FirstValue

q=( Place
   .objects
   .annotate(
        avg_rating=Window(
            expression=FirstValue('feedback_set__rating'),
            partition_by=[F('feedback_set__profile'),
                          F('feedback_set__place')],
            order_by=F('feedback_set__timestamp').desc()
        )
     )
    .values(
        place_name=F('feedback_set__place__name'),
     )
    .annotate(
        rating=Avg('avg_rating')
     )
)
```

Underlying SQL:

```
>>> print (q.query)

SELECT
   T4."name" AS "place_name",
   AVG(FIRST_VALUE("a_profileplacefeedback"."rating") 
       OVER (PARTITION BY "a_profileplacefeedback"."profile_id", 
                          "a_profileplacefeedback"."place_id" 
             ORDER BY "a_profileplacefeedback"."timestamp" DESC)) AS "rating" 
FROM
   "a_place" 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN
      "a_profileplacefeedback" 
      ON ("a_place"."id" = "a_profileplacefeedback"."place_id") 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN
      "a_place" T4 
      ON ("a_profileplacefeedback"."place_id" = T4."id") 
GROUP BY
   T4."name"
```

Comment: This definitely fails. At first, you filtering ```Profile``` objects. But I need to calculate an average rating for a given place and filtering only last rating left by profile.

Comment: Was my bad. Asking for more explanations before venturing with an answer was the way. _"only last rating left by profile"_ is not on your question.

Comment: My bad too. Emphasized related word in question. Thank you

Comment: I misunderstand _"I need to retrieve all LAST User feedbacks and sum up all "_ . Now I understand you, it means: _"I need to retrieve LASTEST feedback for each user and sum up all "_. Not the same _"all last user feedbacks"_ than _"latest feedback"_. Troubles with my English, srr. :(

Comment: I posted the answer. Written with django 2.2.0.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need this or something similar:

```
place.feedback_set.values('profile').annotate(rating_sum=Sum(rating)).values('profile','rating_sum').order_by('profile')
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But I think you missed one thing: I need to take the last rating by each user.