# Django filtering error: annotate + distinct not implemented

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm using Django 2.2 and I need to group a query set by month and count the number of rows

Input:

```
Id | Value | Date

1  | Example value 1 | 2020-02-10
2  | Example value 2 | 2020-02-17
3  | Example value 3 | 2020-03-21
4  | Example value 4 | 2020-04-15
```

Expected output

```
Month | Count

2020-02 | 2 
2020-03 | 1
2020-04 | 1
```

I'm using an initial filtering like this.

```
details = Process.objects.filter(started_at__gte=start_date, finished_at__lte=end_date).order_by('-serial_number').distinct('serial_number')
#Some code using all details
#Filtering
```

After that I need to do the group by and count.

```
summary = (details
          .annotate(m=Month('started_at'))
          .values('m')
          .annotate(total=Count('id'))
          .order_by('id').distinct('m','id'))
```

But when I execute it I got the following error:

> NotImplementedError: annotate() + distinct(fields) is not implemented.

Month class definition:

```
class Month(F):
    function = 'EXTRACT'
    template = '%(function)s(MONTH from %(expressions)s)'
    output_field = models.IntegerField()
```

I'm trying to do something like this.

[Django: Query Group By Month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37851053/django-query-group-by-month)

Comment: what if you don't call ***`.distinct('m','id')`***?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django: NotImplementedError: annotate() + distinct(fields) is not implemented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38583295/django-notimplementederror-annotate-distinctfields-is-not-implemented)

Comment: @ArakkalAbu got the same error