# How to do search with priority in django?

Tags: mysql, django, django-rest-framework, django-filter, django-rest-framework-filters

I'm using djangorestframework with mysql database.
I have a view that returns a list based on a search query param.
I'm using rest_frameworks.filters SearchFilter for the search based filtering.
Here's my view:

```
from rest_framework import filters
from rest_framework.generics import ListAPIView
...

class FooListView(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = SymbolSerializer
    queryset = Symbol.objects.all()
    filter_backends = [filters.SearchFilter]
    search_fields = ['field_A', 'field_B', 'field_C']
```

An example URL to call is:

```
http://localhost:8000/symbols/symbols/?search=bird
```

Now everything works fine but I need a feature that filters.SearchFilter doesn't support.
I want my search to be ordered by priority of search_fields.

For example here's two records:

> foo1 : {"field_A": "any", "field_B": "many", "field_C": "bar", "id": 3}
>
> foo2 : {"field_A": "many", "field_B": "any", "field_C": "bar", "id": 4}

Now when I do a search with search=**'many'** param, I want the view to return me a list which foo2 record is higher that foo1 ( like this [foo2, foo1] ) because I want the search's priority to be field_A score but It just returns me a list that is sorted by id ([foo1, foo2]).

Any help?

Answer (score 2):

I just stumbled into this same exact problem.

My solution was to tweak the searching logic of DRF's `filters.SearchFilter` a little bit using inspiration from [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58593423) and ended up with the following custom filter class:

```py
class PriorizedSearchFilter(filters.SearchFilter):
    def filter_queryset(self, request, queryset, view):
        """Override to return priorized results."""
        # Copy paste from DRF
        search_fields = getattr(view, 'search_fields', None)
        search_terms = self.get_search_terms(request)

        if not search_fields or not search_terms:
            return queryset

        orm_lookups = [
            self.construct_search(six.text_type(search_field))
            for search_field in search_fields
        ]
        base = queryset
        conditions = []

        # Will contain a queryset for each search term
        querysets = list()

        for search_term in search_terms:
            queries = [
                models.Q(**{orm_lookup: search_term})
                for orm_lookup in orm_lookups
            ]

            # Conditions for annotated priority value. Priority == inverse of the search field's index.
            # Example: 
            #   search_fields = ['field_A', 'field_B', 'field_C']
            #   Priorities are field_A = 2, field_B = 1, field_C = 0
            when_conditions = [models.When(queries[i], then=models.Value(len(queries) - i - 1)) for i in range(len(queries))]
            
            # Generate queryset result for this search term, with annotated priority
            querysets.append(
                queryset.filter(reduce(operator.or_, queries))
                    .annotate(priority=models.Case(
                        *when_conditions,
                        output_field=models.IntegerField(),
                        default=models.Value(-1)) # Lowest possible priority
                    )
                )

        # Intersect all querysets and order by highest priority
        queryset = reduce(operator.and_, querysets).order_by('-priority')

        # Copy paste from DRF
        if self.must_call_distinct(queryset, search_fields):
            # Filtering against a many-to-many field requires us to
            # call queryset.distinct() in order to avoid duplicate items
            # in the resulting queryset.
            # We try to avoid this if possible, for performance reasons.
            queryset = distinct(queryset, base)
        return queryset
```

Use `filter_backends = [PrioritizedSearchFilter]` and you're set.

Answer (score 0):

[Maximiliano's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64161260/22174384) is almost perfect, but there is a bug with duplicate entries in it. If the search word matches the object in more than one field, then `queryset`'s `distinct` will regard the same object annotated with different priorities as different objects. As a result, the search filter will return duplicated entries.

Since Django 3.2, the solution is as simple as replacing `annotate` with `alias`. From it's [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#alias),

> Same as `annotate()`, but instead of annotating objects in the QuerySet, saves the expression for later reuse with other QuerySet methods. (...) `alias()` can be used in conjunction with `annotate()`, `exclude()`, `filter()`, `order_by()`, and `update()`.

In other words, `alias` solves the problem because it can be used with `order_by` but is disregarded by `distinct`.