# Search by ordered username in Django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

I want to filter users by their username and order them by pertinence. The users with username matching perfectly the query should be first, then usernames starting with the query and finally usernames containing the query.

Admitting I have users with the following usernames : "Phoenix123", "Phoenix", "i_m_phoenix", "phoenix123", "ImPhoenix" and "phoenix"

If I want to search for users whose username contains "Phoenix", I want to have a quesyset of users whose username are in this order :
"Phoenix", "phoenix", "Phoenix123", "phoenix123", "ImPhoenix", "i_m_phoenix"

I've tried this : [How to chain Django querysets preserving individual order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18235419/how-to-chain-django-querysets-preserving-individual-order)

```
    user_perfect = Q(username__exact=username)  # get Phoenix if exists
    user_perfect_to_lower = Q(username__iexact=username)  # get phoenix if exists
    users_starting_perfect = Q(username__startswith=username)  # get Phoenix123 if exists
    users_starting_lower = Q(username__istartswith=username)  # get phoenix123 if exists
    users_containing_perfect = Q(username__contains=username)  # get ImPhoenix if exists
    users_containing_lower = Q(username__icontains=username)  # get im_phoenix if exists

    result = (
        User.objects.filter(
            user_perfect | user_perfect_to_lower | users_starting_perfect | users_starting_lower |
            users_containing_perfect | users_containing_lower).annotate(
            search_type_ordering=Case(
                When(user_perfect, then=Value(6)),
                When(user_perfect_to_lower, then=Value(5)),
                When(users_starting_perfect, then=Value(4)),
                When(users_starting_lower, then=Value(3)),
                When(users_containing_perfect, then=Value(2)),
                When(users_containing_lower, then=Value(1)),
                default=Value(-1),
                output_field=IntegerField(),
            )
        ).order_by('-search_type_ordering').distinct()[:10]
    )
```

But If I print the result, the search_type_ordering field is wrong for the users_starting_lower and users_containing_lower :

```
<QuerySet [{'username': 'Phoenix', 'search_type_ordering': 6}, 
{'username': 'phoenix', 'search_type_ordering': 5}, 
{'username': 'Phoenix123', 'search_type_ordering': 4}, 
{'username': 'phoenix123', 'search_type_ordering': 4}, 
{'username': 'ImPhoenix', 'search_type_ordering': 2}, 
{'username': 'i_m_phoenix', 'search_type_ordering': 2}]>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Try this approach:

The less desired match should give you 1 point. Almost the weakes match gives you 10 = 10 points. The next match gives you 100 points and the most desired match gives you 10 * (match cares num - 1) points.

I've annotated this point in separate fields and then in the same queryset summed it in another annotated field. And then sorted by sum.

Let me know if you need implementation help. I'll try to install Django and remember how to use it)

Btw, this isn't the best idea to search in db like this. I've changee my mind using mentioned above approach. The best approach is using FTS search engines like Elasticaearch/Algolia/Sphinx etc

Comment: Hi. I don't really get why I would need to have a point system here and how it would be different from my current annotation. Could you add an example ? I didn't know I could use something else to do this kind of search, I will give the ones you mentioned a look. Thanks for your help !