# Django combine 2 querysets without changing the original order

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

```py
def get_queryset(self):
    normal_posts = Post.objects.filter(field1='value1').order_by('another_field_1')
    featured_posts = Post.objects.filter(field2='value2').order_by('another_field_2')
        
    all_posts = (normal_posts | featured_posts) #does not preserve the order
    return all_posts
```

I'm using DjangoFilterBackend and along with filterset_class for paginated query results. Hence not able to use below.

```
    normal_posts.union(featured_posts) #django.db.utils.NotSupportedError: Calling QuerySet.filter() after union() is not supported.
```

I tried using **from itertools import chain** also, however its not much helpful as its returning a list and not query set.

Please suggest.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to chain Django querysets preserving individual order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18235419/how-to-chain-django-querysets-preserving-individual-order)

Comment: @blhsing - thanks for your efforts, but I need to make sure invidiual Q's are sorted based on their own logic. Hence i cannot go ahead with global order by option on the final query set.

Comment: @CharithNidarsha can you provide an example with some data what is the expected result?

Answer (score -1):

To allow each filter to have its own order option while merging the two, you can adapt this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58593423/6890912) to a very similar question with an additional annotation based on the queryset filter in effect and use it as a secondary key for `order_by`:

```
normal_posts = Q(field1='value1')
featured_posts = Q(field2='value2')
all_posts = (
    Post.objects
    .filter(normal_posts| featured_posts)
    .annotate(
        post_type=Case(
            When(normal_posts, then=Value(1)),
            When(featured_posts, then=Value(2)),
            output_field=IntegerField(),
        )
    )
    .annotate(
        type_specific_ordering=Case(
            When(normal_posts, then=F('another_field_1')),
            When(featured_posts, then=F('another_field_2'))
        )
    )
    .order_by('post_type', 'type_specific_ordering')
)
```